# Extract Stamp image from Appearance

Tags: c#, debugging, pdf

I am trying to extract an image saved as a stamp in a PDf. I was able to understand most of the stream except the part after line 20

```
q
1649.578 1427.348 m
1649.578 1410.377 l
1666.795 1410.377 l
1666.795 1427.348 l
h
W*
n
q
0.12 0 0 0.12 0 0 cm
/R8 gs
1 1 1 rg
1 J
1 j
0 0 0 RG
2 w
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
13756 11759 124 125 re
f 
**//Line 20 is here**
1.70146 w
1.70164 w
1.70146 w
1.70253 w
0.0900879 0.0900879 0.0900879 RG
1.70573 w
1.70565 w
1.7862 w
1.78278 w
0 0 0 RG
1.99706 w
1.82521 w
0.0900879 0.0900879 0.0900879 RG
1.99401 w
1.98696 w
1.97996 w
1.97313 w
1.96622 w
1.95937 w
1.86222 w
1.85607 w
1.84996 w
1.84389 w
1.83797 w
1.83198 w
1.82602 w
1.82011 w
1.81424 w
1.8084 w
1.8026 w
1.79694 w
1.79121 w
1.78552 w
1.99828 w
1.9912 w
1.98418 w
1.9772 w
1.97026 w
1.96338 w
1.85978 w
1.85364 w
1.84755 w
1.8415 w
1.83548 w
1.82951 w
1.82367 w
1.81778 w
1.81192 w
1.80609 w
1.80031 w
1.79456 w
1.78895 w
1.78327 w
0 0 0 RG
1.90934 w
1.85217 w
1.90043 w
0.0900879 0.0900879 0.0900879 RG
1.95034 w
1.9436 w
1.9369 w
1.93036 w
1.92376 w
1.9172 w
1.91068 w
1.90421 w
1.89778 w
1.89139 w
1.88516 w
1.87885 w
1.87259 w
1.86638 w
1.8602 w
1.85406 w
1.84797 w
1.84202 w
1.836 w
1.83002 w
1.78366 w
1.95303 w
1.94638 w
1.93967 w
1.933 w
1.92637 w
1.91979 w
1.91326 w
1.90677 w
1.90043 w
1.89403 w
1.88767 w
1.88135 w
1.87507 w
1.86884 w
1.86264 w
1.8566 w
1.85049 w
1.84441 w
1.83838 w
1.83239 w
1.78591 w
0 0 0 RG
1.82869 w
1.84181 w
1.96705 w
1.87994 w
1.88081 w
1.98321 w
1.95749 w
1.88537 w
1.86959 w
1.86937 w
0.0900879 0.0900879 0.0900879 RG
1.70609 w
1.9051 w
0 0 0 RG
1.87012 w
1.91012 w
1.94546 w
1.92251 w
1.88778 w
5.11881 w
5.10412 w
1.706 w
1.70191 w
1.70253 w
1.70288 w
1.70565 w
5.34455 w
5.34631 w
5.36067 w
1.7821 w
1.78152 w
1.78659 w
1.7862 w
1.78317 w
1.78278 w
1.7821 w
1.73589 w
1.74127 w
1.95608 w
1.86959 w
1.78689 w
1.74257 w
1.73589 w
3.50481 w
1.74977 w
1.74799 w
1.7464 w
1.74518 w
1.74443 w
1.74415 w
1.75184 w
1.75637 w
1.76092 w
1.76522 w
1.76914 w
1.7727 w
1.77579 w
1.77831 w
1.78006 w
1.78123 w
3.50368 w
1.75184 w
5.11881 w
5.12176 w
5.34455 w
5.34777 w
3.41451 w
3.48626 w
1.70725 w
1.74127 w
1.70725 w
5.22939 w
5.23246 w
5.34777 w
5.59849 w
5.34777 w
5.87352 w
5.87352 w
1.95819 w
1.95855 w
1.86552 w
1.78259 w
1.95855 w
1.95937 w
1.86478 w
1.78259 w
1.95937 w
1.95819 w
1.86574 w
1.78259 w
1.95819 w
1.86574 w
1.78259 w
1.86574 w
1.95784 w
5.11881 w
5.12256 w
5.11881 w
5.36067 w
5.34455 w
5.4836 w
5.60876 w
5.83671 w
5.87352 w
5.4836 w
1.7863 w
1.95714 w
1.82828 w
1.78562 w
1.7863 w
1.78152 w
1.95631 w
1.95714 w
1.82848 w
1.70627 w
1.78562 w
1.78152 w
1.95631 w
1.8292 w
1.70627 w
1.78562 w
1.78152 w
1.95631 w
1.8292 w
1.70627 w
1.78317 w
1.78152 w
1.86638 w
1.94209 w
1.82828 w
1.70627 w
1.78659 w
1.95737 w
1.94522 w
1.86937 w
1.82828 w
1.82787 w
1.78152 w
5.87352 w
5.85243 w
5.94384 w
5.85243 w
5.73708 w
5.76345 w
5.64274 w
5.43394 w
5.65187 w
5.56884 w
5.65187 w
5.36067 w
5.36891 w
1.78689 w
1.8807 w
1.95081 w
1.95749 w
1.91236 w
1.81131 w
1.78659 w
1.7862 w
1.78317 w
1.78278 w
1.7821 w
1.95081 w
1.91236 w
1.81131 w
1.78659 w
1.78689 w
5.87352 w
5.8619 w
5.87352 w
5.87246 w
5.8619 w
1.95749 w
1.95432 w
1.95749 w
5.83671 w
5.60876 w
1.86959 w
1.94522 w
1.95397 w
1.95432 w
1.86937 w
1.86959 w
1.95397 w
5.60876 w
5.59849 w
5.59913 w
5.60876 w
5.59849 w
1.86937 w
1.86616 w
1.86937 w
1.86638 w
1.79091 w
1.79496 w
1.79882 w
1.8023 w
1.80539 w
1.8079 w
1.8098 w
1.81091 w
3.58183 w
3.57927 w
1.8926 w
1.89106 w
1.88876 w
1.88581 w
1.88222 w
1.87831 w
1.87399 w
1.86959 w
3.73918 w
3.78673 w
3.73918 w
1.92877 w
1.92945 w
1.93105 w
1.93346 w
1.93656 w
1.94036 w
1.94464 w
1.94918 w
3.85753 w
3.90794 w
1.95972 w
3.92133 w
3.92133 w
1.96067 w
1.95878 w
1.96067 w
1.95972 w
1.95878 w
1.95972 w
1.95972 w
3.91568 w
3.91945 w
3.91568 w
1.78856 w
3.57868 w
3.65082 w
3.57868 w
1.78934 w
1.78767 w
1.78934 w
1.78856 w
1.78767 w
1.82705 w
1.82623 w
1.82541 w
1.78856 w
1.82623 w
1.78856 w
3.65246 w
3.65573 w
3.65246 w
3.57378 w
3.57711 w
3.57378 w
1.9127 w
3.82719 w
3.90981 w
3.82719 w
1.91359 w
1.9118 w
1.9127 w
1.91359 w
1.9118 w
1.95491 w
1.95584 w
1.9569 w
1.9127 w
1.95584 w
1.9127 w
3.91169 w
3.91568 w
3.91169 w
3.82181 w
3.82539 w
3.82181 w
1.86787 w
3.73746 w
3.81621 w
3.73746 w
1.86873 w
1.86702 w
1.86787 w
1.86873 w
1.86702 w
1.90811 w
1.909 w
1.9099 w
1.86787 w
1.909 w
1.86787 w
3.818 w
3.82181 w
3.818 w
3.73233 w
3.73575 w
3.73233 w
1.73997 w
1.74127 w
1.73997 w
1.74127 w
1.74257 w
1.73589 w
1.70752 w
1.70627 w
1.73589 w
1.70627 w
1.71174 w
1.71832 w
1.72505 w
1.73183 w
1.70627 w
1.71742 w
1.72724 w
1.70627 w
1.71742 w
1.72724 w
1.70627 w
1.71742 w
1.72724 w
1.70627 w
1.71742 w
1.72724 w
1.70627 w
1.71742 w
1.72724 w
1.70627 w
1.71742 w
1.72724 w
1.70627 w
1.71742 w
1.72724 w
1.70627 w
1.71742 w
1.72724 w
1.70627 w
1.71742 w
1.72724 w
1.70627 w
1.71742 w
1.72724 w
1.70627 w
1.71742 w
1.72724 w
1.70627 w
1.71174 w
1.71841 w
1.72505 w
1.73183 w
1.73589 w
1.70627 w
1.73589 w
1.72095 w
1.71787 w
1.72095 w
1.7346 w
1.73589 w
1.7346 w
1.73589 w
1.7346 w
1.73589 w
1.7346 w
1.73589 w
1.74257 w
1.73774 w
1.74257 w
1.73774 w
1.73589 w
1.73774 w
1.7346 w
5.11774 w
5.11052 w
3.40844 w
3.40719 w
5.11774 w
5.11052 w
1.70591 w
1.70351 w
3.40719 w
3.40844 w
3.40719 w
1.70351 w
1.70591 w
5.11052 w
5.11774 w
5.11052 w
5.11774 w
5.11052 w
1.70627 w
1.70324 w
1.70609 w
3.50274 w
1.74874 w
1.74687 w
1.74537 w
1.74415 w
1.74332 w
1.74313 w
1.75071 w
1.75533 w
1.75978 w
1.76416 w
1.76809 w
1.77164 w
1.77473 w
1.77715 w
1.77899 w
1.78006 w
3.50142 w
1.75071 w
5.12256 w
5.12552 w
5.34134 w
5.34455 w
3.41701 w
3.48421 w
1.70851 w
5.22631 w
5.22939 w
1.70609 w
1.70324 w
1.70627 w
1.70752 w
1.70716 w
1.85628 w
1.84483 w
1.83362 w
1.82255 w
1.81161 w
1.80071 w
1.79003 w
1.77948 w
1.76905 w
1.75864 w
1.74846 w
1.73839 w
1.72843 w
1.7185 w
1.70716 w
1.85628 w
1.84483 w
1.83362 w
1.82255 w
1.81161 w
1.80071 w
1.79003 w
1.77948 w
1.76905 w
1.75864 w
1.74846 w
1.73839 w
1.72843 w
1.7185 w
1.70716 w
1.85628 w
1.84483 w
1.83362 w
1.82255 w
1.81161 w
1.80071 w
1.79003 w
1.77948 w
1.76905 w
1.75864 w
1.74846 w
1.73839 w
1.72843 w
1.7185 w
1.70716 w
1.73275 w
1.79357 w
5.60876 w
5.64274 w
1.86959 w
1.86937 w
1.86638 w
1.86937 w
1.86959 w
1.8807 w
1.95397 w
1.73589 w
1.73718 w
1.73589 w
1.73718 w
1.73589 w
1.78885 w
1.79023 w
1.78885 w
1.79023 w
1.78885 w
1.86648 w
1.86499 w
1.86648 w
1.86499 w
1.86648 w
1.70716 w
1.706 w
1.70716 w
1.706 w
1.70716 w
1.86499 w
1.86648 w
1.70716 w
1.70591 w
1.70716 w
1.70591 w
1.86499 w
1.70591 w
1.86648 w
1.70716 w
1.86499 w
1.90376 w
1.89601 w
1.89623 w
1.89733 w
1.89689 w
1.897 w
1.89711 w
1.89722 w
1.90287 w
1.90298 w
1.90309 w
1.9032 w
1.90265 w
1.90521 w
1.90465 w
1.90376 w
1.90265 w
1.90143 w
1.89999 w
1.90543 w
1.90521 w
1.90476 w
1.90409 w
1.9032 w
1.90265 w
1.89733 w
1.89469 w
1.89491 w
1.89535 w
1.89623 w
1.89733 w
1.89866 w
1.89469 w
1.8959 w
1.89524 w
1.8948 w
1.89469 w
1.89722 w
1.90165 w
1.90043 w
1.89943 w
1.89833 w
1.90165 w
1.90154 w
1.90143 w
1.90132 w
1.90121 w
1.9011 w
1.90087 w
1.90076 w
1.90065 w
1.90054 w
1.90043 w
1.90054 w
1.90065 w
1.90076 w
1.90087 w
1.9011 w
1.90121 w
1.90132 w
1.90143 w
1.90154 w
1.90165 w
1.89943 w
1.89932 w
1.89921 w
1.89899 w
1.89888 w
1.89877 w
1.89866 w
1.89844 w
1.89833 w
1.89844 w
1.89866 w
1.89877 w
1.89888 w
1.89899 w
1.89921 w
1.89932 w
1.89943 w
1.89767 w
1.90154 w
1.90143 w
1.90132 w
1.90121 w
1.9011 w
1.90087 w
1.90076 w
1.90065 w
1.90054 w
1.90065 w
1.90076 w
1.90087 w
1.9011 w
1.90121 w
1.90132 w
1.90143 w
1.90154 w
1.89943 w
1.89932 w
1.89921 w
1.89899 w
1.89888 w
1.89877 w
1.89866 w
1.89844 w
1.89833 w
1.89844 w
1.89866 w
1.89877 w
1.89888 w
1.89899 w
1.89921 w
1.89932 w
1.89943 w
1.89767 w
1.90232 w
1.90376 w
1.90365 w
1.89634 w
1.90365 w
1.90376 w
1.89458 w
1.89502 w
1.89458 w
1.90409 w
1.89579 w
1.8959 w
1.89579 w
1.8959 w
1.90421 w
1.90409 w
1.90232 w
1.90421 w
1.90409 w
1.90387 w
1.89579 w
1.8959 w
1.89579 w
1.8959 w
1.90543 w
1.90487 w
1.90432 w
1.90343 w
1.90221 w
1.90198 w
1.90099 w
1.89966 w
1.89844 w
1.89778 w
1.90087 w
1.89955 w
1.89844 w
1.898 w
1.89767 w
1.89458 w
1.89678 w
1.89579 w
1.89513 w
1.89491 w
1.90376 w
1.90454 w
1.90498 w
1.90543 w
1.89623 w
1.89711 w
1.89833 w
1.89966 w
1.90099 w
1.90232 w
1.90343 w
1.89491 w
1.89513 w
1.89568 w
1.89458 w
1.92956 w
1.92922 w
1.92899 w
1.92877 w
1.92865 w
1.92877 w
1.92899 w
1.92922 w
1.92956 w
1.92991 w
1.93025 w
1.93048 w
1.93071 w
1.93094 w
1.93105 w
1.93094 w
1.93071 w
1.93048 w
1.93025 w
1.92991 w
1.93071 w
1.92047 w
1.9181 w
1.94175 w
1.9181 w
1.92047 w
1.93944 w
1.92047 w
1.88778 w
1.88788 w
1.88799 w
1.88788 w
1.88778 w
1.87335 w
1.87324 w
1.87313 w
1.87324 w
1.87335 w
1.88113 w
1.88059 w
1.87994 w
1.87972 w
1.87994 w
1.88059 w
1.88113 w
1.88723 w
1.88636 w
1.88701 w
1.87475 w
1.87389 w
1.8741 w
1.87389 w
1.8741 w
1.87389 w
1.87475 w
1.88701 w
1.88636 w
1.88778 w
1.88767 w
1.87346 w
1.87335 w
1.87346 w
1.88767 w
1.88778 w
5.83671 w
5.82524 w
1.94522 w
1.94175 w
1.94522 w
1.94209 w
1.94522 w
1.9181 w
1.91799 w
1.9258 w
1.92569 w
1.92455 w
1.92512 w
1.92501 w
1.92489 w
1.92478 w
1.919 w
1.91889 w
1.91878 w
1.91866 w
1.91923 w
1.91641 w
1.91663 w
1.9172 w
1.91799 w
1.91911 w
1.92047 w
1.91641 w
1.91652 w
1.91697 w
1.91776 w
1.91923 w
1.92455 w
1.92717 w
1.9266 w
1.9258 w
1.92467 w
1.9233 w
1.92183 w
1.9274 w
1.92512 w
1.92603 w
1.92671 w
1.92717 w
1.92024 w
1.92138 w
1.9224 w
1.92364 w
1.92024 w
1.92036 w
1.92058 w
1.9207 w
1.92081 w
1.92092 w
1.92115 w
1.92126 w
1.92138 w
1.92126 w
1.92115 w
1.92092 w
1.92081 w
1.9207 w
1.92058 w
1.92036 w
1.92024 w
1.9224 w
1.92251 w
1.92262 w
1.92274 w
1.92285 w
1.92308 w
1.92319 w
1.9233 w
1.92342 w
1.92353 w
1.92364 w
1.92353 w
1.92342 w
1.9233 w
1.92319 w
1.92308 w
1.92285 w
1.92274 w
1.92262 w
1.92251 w
1.9224 w
1.91957 w
1.92024 w
1.92036 w
1.92058 w
1.9207 w
1.92081 w
1.92092 w
1.92115 w
1.92126 w
1.92138 w
1.92126 w
1.92115 w
1.92092 w
1.92081 w
1.9207 w
1.92058 w
1.92036 w
1.92024 w
1.92251 w
1.92262 w
1.92274 w
1.92285 w
1.92308 w
1.92319 w
1.9233 w
1.92342 w
1.92353 w
1.92342 w
1.9233 w
1.92319 w
1.92308 w
1.92285 w
1.92274 w
1.92262 w
1.92251 w
1.91957 w
1.92433 w
1.91957 w
1.91799 w
1.9181 w
1.92558 w
1.92569 w
1.92558 w
1.9181 w
1.91799 w
1.9274 w
1.92614 w
1.91641 w
1.91697 w
1.92614 w
1.92603 w
1.92614 w
1.92626 w
1.92614 w
1.92603 w
1.91765 w
1.91776 w
1.91765 w
1.91776 w
1.91765 w
1.92603 w
1.92614 w
1.92626 w
1.92433 w
1.91641 w
1.91674 w
1.91697 w
1.91753 w
1.91844 w
1.91968 w
1.92058 w
1.92092 w
1.92228 w
1.92353 w
1.91991 w
1.92104 w
1.92228 w
1.92353 w
1.92421 w
1.92717 w
1.92751 w
1.92398 w
1.92523 w
1.92626 w
1.92683 w
1.92717 w
1.91731 w
1.91686 w
1.91674 w
1.91641 w
1.92478 w
1.92353 w
1.92217 w
1.92081 w
1.91957 w
1.91844 w
1.9181 w
1.92694 w
1.92637 w
1.9258 w
1.9274 w
1.89227 w
1.8926 w
1.89282 w
1.89315 w
1.89326 w
1.89337 w
1.89326 w
1.89315 w
1.89282 w
1.8926 w
1.89227 w
1.89194 w
1.89172 w
1.89139 w
1.89128 w
1.89106 w
1.89128 w
1.89139 w
1.89172 w
1.89194 w
1.8832 w
1.89315 w
1.88091 w
1.90376 w
1.8832 w
1.90143 w
1.93449 w
1.93437 w
1.93449 w
1.94999 w
1.95011 w
1.94999 w
1.93449 w
1.9414 w
1.94163 w
1.94221 w
1.94279 w
1.94221 w
1.94163 w
1.9414 w
1.93506 w
1.93541 w
1.93506 w
1.93598 w
1.94918 w
1.94848 w
1.94941 w
1.94848 w
1.94918 w
1.93598 w
1.93506 w
1.93541 w
1.93449 w
1.9346 w
1.93472 w
1.94988 w
1.94999 w
1.94988 w
1.93472 w
1.9346 w
1.93449 w
5.63234 w
5.64274 w
1.87766 w
1.8807 w
1.87766 w
5.64274 w
1.88091 w
1.95397 w
1.88091 w
1.8807 w
3.73254 w
3.78629 w
3.73254 w
3.76791 w
3.77031 w
3.76791 w
3.77031 w
3.82225 w
3.82472 w
3.82225 w
3.8227 w
3.82225 w
3.94005 w
3.88188 w
3.84479 w
3.84457 w
3.84479 w
3.8423 w
3.90162 w
3.89906 w
3.90162 w
3.89906 w
2 w
13880 11884 m
13756 11884 l
S
13756 11884 m
13756 11759 l
S
13756 11759 m
13880 11759 l
S
13880 11759 m
13880 11884 l
S
1.97768 w
1.97936 w
1.97768 w
1.97936 w
1.97768 w
1.97936 w
1.97936 w
5.29995 w
5.28792 w
5.28192 w
5.19053 w
5.30599 w
1.7787 w
1.77899 w
1.77996 w
1.78142 w
1.78308 w
1.78464 w
1.78581 w
1.7865 w
1.78581 w
1.78464 w
1.78308 w
1.78142 w
1.77996 w
1.77899 w
1.7787 w
2 w
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
2 w
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
2 w
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
6 w
0.219727 0.325439 0.498047 RG
0.941406 0.941406 0.941406 rg
2 w
0 0 0 RG
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
1.93713 w
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1.95784 w
1.84734 w
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1.86616 w
1.7655 w
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1.78259 w
1.69052 w
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1.70627 w
1.64381 w
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1.67377 w
1.71896 w
1.73478 w
1.7757 w
1.79259 w
1.83631 w
1.85438 w
1.90121 w
1.92058 w
1.97086 w
1.99169 w
1.64381 w
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1.67377 w
1.71896 w
1.73478 w
1.7757 w
1.79259 w
1.83631 w
1.85438 w
1.90121 w
1.92058 w
1.97086 w
1.99169 w
1.64381 w
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1.67377 w
1.71896 w
1.73478 w
1.7757 w
1.79259 w
1.83631 w
1.85438 w
1.90121 w
1.92058 w
1.97086 w
1.99169 w
1.64381 w
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1.85122 w
1.83321 w
1.78964 w
1.7728 w
1.73202 w
1.71624 w
1.67377 w
1.64381 w
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1.85122 w
1.83321 w
1.78964 w
1.7728 w
1.73202 w
1.71624 w
1.67377 w
1.64381 w
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1.85122 w
1.83321 w
1.78964 w
1.7728 w
1.73202 w
1.71624 w
1.67377 w
2 w
1.98164 w
1.98164 w
1.79555 w
1.83983 w
1.79555 w
1.73349 w
1.77473 w
1.73349 w
1.91551 w
2 w
1.79634 w
1.8017 w
1.81262 w
1.96907 w
1.97564 w
1.98877 w
2 w
1.91686 w
1.92296 w
1.93541 w
1.87637 w
1.88233 w
1.89425 w
2 w
1.93082 w
1.95937 w
1.94036 w
1.93679 w
1.96551 w
1.94638 w
1.85049 w
1.87658 w
1.85914 w
1.78425 w
1.8085 w
1.79229 w
1.74715 w
1.7703 w
1.75486 w
1.74612 w
1.76934 w
1.75382 w
1.87045 w
1.897 w
1.87929 w
2 w
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
1.71832 w
1.83362 w
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
2 w
0 0 0 rg
1.74565 w
1.74229 w
1.69907 w
1.61426 w
1.69907 w
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1.70048 w
11.0908 w
11.0815 w
1.70627 w
1.78259 w
11.5868 w
11.5767 w
1.78259 w
1.86616 w
12.1301 w
12.1183 w
1.86616 w
1.95784 w
12.726 w
12.7137 w
1.95784 w
2 w
0 0 0 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1.68197 w
10.9328 w
10.9238 w
1.67635 w
1.68197 w
10.9328 w
10.9238 w
1.67635 w
1.68197 w
10.9328 w
10.9238 w
1.67635 w
1.68197 w
10.9328 w
10.9238 w
1.67635 w
1.68197 w
10.9328 w
10.9238 w
1.67635 w
1.68197 w
10.9328 w
10.9238 w
1.67635 w
1.68197 w
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1.76982 w
1.76828 w
1.66386 w
1.67747 w
1.69131 w
1.7052 w
1.71932 w
1.73349 w
1.7478 w
1.76207 w
1.58245 w
1.66386 w
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
5.46582 w
0.219727 0.325439 0.498047 RG
5.46338 w
5.45911 w
5.45363 w
5.44725 w
5.44059 w
5.43363 w
5.4276 w
5.42219 w
5.41798 w
5.41528 w
5.41438 w
5.41528 w
5.41798 w
5.42219 w
5.4276 w
5.43363 w
5.44059 w
5.44725 w
5.45363 w
5.45911 w
5.46338 w
5.46582 w
0.941406 0.941406 0.941406 rg
6 w
5.24284 w
5.2406 w
5.23667 w
5.23162 w
5.22575 w
5.21962 w
5.21322 w
5.20739 w
5.2024 w
5.19881 w
5.19632 w
5.19549 w
5.19632 w
5.19881 w
5.2024 w
5.20739 w
5.21322 w
5.21962 w
5.22575 w
5.23162 w
5.23667 w
5.2406 w
5.24284 w
6 w
4.17949 w
0 0 0 RG
4.6938 w
4.17949 w
1.39316 w
4.17949 w
4.6938 w
4.17949 w
4.6938 w
4.17949 w
1.39316 w
4.17949 w
4.6938 w
4.17949 w
4.71234 w
4.16507 w
5.91723 w
4.16507 w
1.90632 w
1.35528 w
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
1 1 1 rg
0 0 0 rg
2 w
1.5873 w
Q
Q
```

According to the PDF specification, I understand that the `w` operator is Line width. But the actual stamp is an image!!! So I am a bit confused. Are these number periods the `w` operator is line width? Or coordinates.

I have created a cleared pdf content with a stamp of 5 X 5 pixels, located at 0,0 (Top left of the document) to simplify my interpretation. [Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Yry3I9BgDlXa5nFiD44BDJBRF2uBgJY_/view?usp=sharing)

The question is, how can I convert such a part after line 20 to an image? Or is it not image-related?

Comment: Thanks for your comment... but why you are saying there is some corruption? I can see the pdf attached to the OP opens just fine

Comment: *opening just fine* does not mean the PDF is not corrupted. Pdf viewers often fix or ignore errors in PDFs when loading them. Details of this may change over time and differ between viewers though, so a broken pdf looking good for you now may look completely different for someone else now or even yourself tomorrow, after a viewer update.

Comment: aha.. makes sense thank you for that. Any hint on how I can distinguish between the file being corrupted and not?

Comment: I don't know which corruptions @KJ has found. My comment was more of a general nature, I just wanted to make clear that the common PDF viewers cannot be used to test for corruption / invalid PDF contents.

Comment: You claim *the actual stamp is an image*. If by "image" you mean a "bitmap image", then no, there is no bitmap image in the file you shared. There are just instructions to fill a rectangle with white and stroke a black border and lots and lots of instructions changing some graphics state parameters again and again.

Comment: *"the file does not reflect the stated intention"* - that is really mildly put ;).

Comment: it seems PDF is converting it to instructions. the actual thing is a snapped shot image used via BlueBleam and saved as a snapshot stamp in the file. when I tried to debug the file to understand how images are placed, I realized in some cases PDF converts it to instructions, which could be to save space or performance. but it seems I have to cross-check the resources then, if there is a `subtype` image then I will stream it out, else, I will use the draw instructions. and it seems those underline 20 are for some other reasons!!!